# How to not duplicate values of input fields while adding a new yii2 dynamic form?

Tags: yii2, duplicates, dynamicform

When I fill all the fields of the first dynamic form, adding a new one all fields are filled in it by the values of the former one. How can I create just empty new form?
I've tried to change this row in controller

```
'modelsEduForm' => (empty($modelsEduForm)) ? [new EduForm] : $modelsEduForm,
```

to

```
  'modelsEduForm' => [new EduForm],
```

But it didn't help.

[image]

Comment: this isnt the default behavior of the dynamic forms they donot replicate old /previous values of the input

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Collecting tabular input](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/input-tabular-input#collecting-tabular-input)

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $modelsEduForms = [new EduForm()];
    for($i = 1; $i < 3; $i++) {
        $modelsEduForms[] = new EduForm();
    }

    if (Model::loadMultiple($modelsEduForms, Yii::$app->request->post()) && Model::validateMultiple($modelsEduForms)) {
        foreach ($modelsEduForms as $modelsEduForm) {
            $modelsEduForm->save(false);
        }
        return $this->redirect('index');
    }

    return $this->render('index', ['modelsEduForms' => $modelsEduForms]);
}
```

Comment: Thx for replying, however I'm already using this logic and it works. But I don't need the same data in the next dynamic form, but it's copied due to some reason

Answer (score 0):

I am sure that is not the default behavior of the dynamic forms as shown in the [demo](https://wbraganca.com/yii2extensions/dynamicform-demo1/create) but there is an event provided with the name `afterInsert` that is triggered whenever a new row is inserted, you can use that event to remove the values from the newly added row see below

```
$js=<<< JS

    $(".dynamicform_wrapper").on("afterInsert", function(e, item) {
        $(item).find('input,textarea,select').each(function(index,element){
           $(element).val('');
        });
    });

JS;
$this->registerJs($js, \yii\web\View::POS_READY);
```